# Functional Equation: $f(2x)=4^x f(x)^2f(x+1)^2$

Tags: recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Here is a very interesting functional equation:

$$f(2x)=4^x f(x)^2f(x+1)^2$$

I found it rather fun to solve, and so I thought I'd share it with the math SE community. Just so you know, I already know the answer to this problem, but I thought the community would find it enjoyable to attempt it.

**HINT:**

> Think about the double-angle formulae of the trigonometric functions.

Comment: You mean I should just try substituting $f(x)=a\sin(\pi x)+b\cos(\pi x)$?  Or perhaps more generally a Fourier series? Hm...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt What I got is neither trigonometric nor periodic (unless I messed up the intermediate calculations, of course). And it's not using OP's hint, either. I am still curious about that, and I guess some prettier solution must exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following proposes a family of solutions, assuming that $\,f\,$ is continuously differentiable.

Let $\,f(x)=2^{-x+2/3}\,g(x)\,$, then:

$$\require{cancel}
\bcancel{2^{-2x+2/3}} g(2x) = \bcancel{2^{2x}}\,\bcancel{2^{-2x+4/3}} g(x)\,\bcancel{2^{-2(x+1)+4/3}}g(x+1) \iff g(2x)=g^2(x)g^2(x+1)
$$

Let $\,g(x)=e^{h(x)}\,$, then:

$$
e^{h(2x)} = e^{2h(x)}e^{2h(x+1)} \iff h(2x) = 2 \big(\,h(x)+h(x+1) \,\big)
$$

Assuming $\,f\,$ is differentiable then so are $\,g\,$ and  $\,h\,$, and:

$$
2 h'(2x) = 2 \big(\,h'(x)+h'(x+1) \,\big) \iff h'(2x) = h'(x)+h'(x+1)
$$

The latter functional equation has the obvious linear solution $\,h'(x)=a(x-1)\,$ with $\,a \in \mathbb{R}\,$.

Tracing the steps back, in the end:

$$
f(x) = 2^{-x+2/3} \cdot c^{x^2 - 2x+2/3} \quad\quad \text{with} \;c \in \mathbb{R}^+
$$

Comment: (+1) Looks nicely done! I believe we could've saved the first step by writing $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ right off the bat

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Right, maybe even $f(x)=2^{g(x)}\,$. What's posted is the steps that I actually followed while solving it. The solution could probably be streamlined further, and the end result itself can be written in different forms e.g. $2^{ax^2 -(2a+1)x+2(a+1)/3}\,$.

Comment: Nice solution! The solution that I had in mind was
$$f(x)=\sin^x \frac{\pi x}{2}$$
but yours works just as well! :D